# Is this a correct way to use Factory Pattern?

Tags: java, design-patterns, factory-method

I have an abstract class which implements the `IDataCreator` interface:

```
public interface IDataCreator
{
    public String getDataString();
}

public abstract class AbstractCreator implements IDataCreator
{
    protected IProject p;

    public AbstractCreator(IProject p) {
       this.p = p;
    }

    public abstract String getDataString();
}
```

Then I have 5 concrete classes which extend `AbstractCreator` and implement the `getDataString()` method:

```
public class ProjectManagerCreator extends AbstractCreator
{
    public ProjectManagerCreator(IProject p) {
       super(p);
    }

    @Override
    public String getDataString() {
       if(p.getLead() != null) {
           String lead = p.getLead().getName();
           return lead;
       }
       return "";
    }    
}
```

Factory class is implemented like this:

```
public class ProjectDataCreatorFactory
{
    IProject p = null;

    public ProjectDataCreatorFactory(IProject p) {
       this.p = p;
    }

    /**
     * Factory method which constructs a object from a given string value.
     * 
     * @param column string of the column name TODO: Implement a interface which maps the strings into static variables
     * @return object which implements the {@link IDataCreator} interface
     */
    public IDataCreator createFromString(String column) {
        IDataCreator creator = null;
        if(column.equals("name")) {
           return new URLCreator(p);
        } else if(column.equals("status")) {
           return new ProjectStatusCreator(p);
        } else if(column.equals("manager")) {
           return new ProjectManagerCreator(p);
        } else if(column.equals("setupdate")) {
           return new ProjectDateCreator(p, ProjectDateCreator.CREATION);
        } else if(column.equals("updatedate")) {
           return new ProjectDateCreator(p, ProjectDateCreator.UPDATED);
        }
        return creator;     
    }        
}
```

The factory class is called like this:

```
ProjectDataCreatorFactory factory = new ProjectDataCreatorFactory(p);
String s = factory.createFromString("name").getDataString();
```

**Question**

Is this the (or a) correct way to use the [Factory Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern)? Is the approach with an interface and an abstract class a good design?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some design considerations:

- **Returning Null**: Your factory method `createFromString` returns a `null` creator if the column is unknown. It's good practice to note this in the javadoc or perhaps throw an `IllegalArgumentException` if a column you can't handle is passed in.
- **Date Abstraction:** `ProjectDateCreator`looks like it could use either its own factory or two separate implementations based on the second constructor argument. That class isn't included here, but it appears `CREATION` and `UPDATED` are some sort of `public static final` type constants. Those would be better expressed as an enum:

  ```
  // A factory can use this instead!
  public enum ProjectDateOption {
      CREATION, UPDATED;
  }
  ```
- **Interface Naming:** Interfaces in Java aren't typically prefixed with an `I`, but if it's consistent through your code then that's a minor quibble.
- **Column Strings**: Your `TODO` mentions this, but the column strings could also be placed into an enum, and then the checking could occur there.

Comment: Thanks for your considerations! I did not use "enums" before but it seems that this is a good way to handle with type constants.

Comment: Enums are the most under-used, yet one of the more powerful Java features. They can be really handy for these types of things: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html

Answer (score 1):

Note that there isn't a so called factory pattern, there is factory method and there is abstract factory.

I would create a separate factory class for ProjectDateCreator.CREATION and ProjectDateCreation.UPDATED. To answer your original question, never be afraid of interfaces and abstract classes. Interfaces are good for you.

Besides an abstract ProjectDateCreator class I would make each factory a singleton and if you know the value of createFromString's String argument compile-time then you can replace it with createURLCreator, createProjectStatusCreator etc. methods. That would make the code a bit more readable (yes, I know, this createFromString method is a small one, but we software developers are even too lazy for that). The IDataCreator --> AbstractCreator --> ProjectManagerCreator inheritance chain is good, no composition is needed here, the abstract class extension is a good approach. I would add that in an abstract class it's not necessary to include unimplemented interface methods.